# Spinner setselection disables my buttons' onclick method

Tags: android, listview, spinner

In my whole day, I worked on this issue.

I have a spinner and expandable listview. My child view has two button first. One is "Accept" other one is "Decline".And my spinner has 4 choice. First is "Waiting requests" Second is "Accepted requests" Third is "Declined requests" Fourth is "All requests"

I want to see that "Waiting requests" when my program first start.
And when I accept or decline I want to that my spinner changes dynamically.
(EDIT: I want to update my dataset not change my spinner. For this I need refresh my spinner. And I called adapter.notifydatasetchanged after filter my data with spinner. I used spinner to filter my data according to record(listview element) category.)
For dynamic changing I first used setSelection(position,true) code. But this is not work. So I used setSelection(0,true); setSelection(position,true);
The reason that why I used two times is because spinner does not update when if it is already selected by the same position. so first I set my position as 0 with this code. 
"setSelection(0,true)" after I set my actual desired position with this code.
"setSelection(position,true)"

With this two code I achive that my spinner is dynamic BUT!!! My buttons which are belong to my listview children are no longer active. I cant click my buttons.

I used thread to run those two code piece but thread also couldnt solve my problem. I am starting to think that this is a bug issue. So I wanted to ask to stackoverflow. I am waiting for any idea?

This is my spinner code:

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            if (oldposition == position)
            {

                if(position!=0) {

                  spinner.setSelection(0, false);
                  spinner.setSelection(position, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    spinner.setSelection(1, false);
                    spinner.setSelection(position, false);
                }

            }

            oldposition = position;

            parentsFiltered.clear();
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Tümü")) {
                parentsFiltered.addAll(yedek);
                parents.clear();
                parents.addAll(parentsFiltered);

            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Onaylananlar")) {
                filter(1);

            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Reddedilenler")) {
                filter(2);

            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Bekleyenler")) {
                filter(0);

            }
            dateFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            parentsFiltered.clear();
            parentsFiltered.addAll(yedek);
            parents.clear();
            parents.addAll(parentsFiltered);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you have any question about my code I am ready to make clear it for you. I did not want to show all my code because i thought that it could be seem complicated. I am a little impatient to hear your ideas because i really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved my issue. I couldnt solve the setselection problem but instead of that way I decided to go from another way. I did not use the setselection method. I just add my filter method also in my accept and decline buttons' onclick methods. That solved the issue.